# two or more .htaccess configuration files to nginx conversion

Tags: mod-rewrite, nginx

I am currently using cPanel shared web hosting and thinking to migrate to nginx powered VPS with cPanel/WHM control panel.
Separate .htaccess files are available for each web site in the each site's directory. There are lot of rewrites in each .htaccess configuration file.

So when I migrate to a nginx server, Do I need to convert all those .htaccess to a one code or what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

yea, if you're going to move to nginx, you need to gather all the htaccess files in all subfolders and add them into the server config of this virtual host, there's a lot of converter sites out there, even though it doesn't always produce optimal config, but i guess it could be a start until you fix them.